# Combine two file into one file

Tags: text-processing, command-line

Suppose I have 2 Files, ABC.txt & DEF.txt with the data shown below as an example:

ABC.txt:

```
abc 14
dka 1
def 51
```

DEF.txt:

```
def 12
ckd 41
```

I want to grep column 1& 2 from both files and write into a third file so that third file contain both file without any repeated column 1 and thire value put for two file and put zero for values that didn't exit in files. How can it be done?

My expected output is (output:

```
       ABC     DEF
abc    14      0
ckd    0       41
def    51      12
dka    1       0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ join -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e 0 <(sort ABC.txt) <(sort DEF.txt)
abc 14 0
ckd 0 41
def 51 12
dka 1 0
```

The header and column spacing are left as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         OFS="\t"; print "", "ABC", "DEF" 
     }
     NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
     { 
         if ($1 in a) { v=a[$1]; delete a[$1] } 
         $3 = v+0 
     }1; 
     END{ for(i in a) print i, 0, a[i] }' DEF.txt ABC.txt
```

The output:

```
    ABC DEF
abc 14  0
dka 1   0
def 51  12
ckd 0   41
```

Answer (score 2):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) has a cross-tabulation (pivot table) option that is quite nice for this sort of thing - although your data would need some pre-processing:

```
awk '{print $0, substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4)}' ABC.txt DEF.txt | 
  datamash -Ws --filler='0' crosstab 1,3 unique 2
        ABC     DEF
abc     14      0
ckd     0       41
def     51      12
dka     1       0
```